# How to use a string instead of the "name" for a properties.resources."name"

Tags: c#, winforms, soundplayer

I have a bunch of audio files stored in resources as I want them to be carried around by the program, I want to assign each file on creation to each soundplayer stored in a soundplayer array, each resources name is the same as strings stored in a different array

```
strings[] names = new string[80];
Soundplayer[] sounds = new Soundplayer[80];
Soundplayer mySound;

for (int i = 0; i < sounds.Length; i++)
{
    sounds[i] = mySound = new Soundplayer(Properties.Resources.names[i])
}
```

it just says the resources does not contain a definition for names, what is the way around this. Is it just that the resoures._____ is not a string?

Comment: If it were me, I'd add an XML file to the project as an "embedded resource" (Right-Click->Properties on the file, then set the 
"Build Action" to "Embedded Resource").  Then, when I wanted to get information sometime later, I'd fish the file out of the application's resources and parse it.  But, that's just the way I think.

Comment: It is heavily optimized to give you access to a specific named resource.  The backdoor is to use Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(names[i]).  But that still requires you to initialize your names[] array, bah.  It isn't a great idea anyway to stuff so many big files in resources, Directory.GetFiles() gets to be a lot more attractive.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it using `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString`:

```
var name = names[i]; // make sure this is initialized
var filename = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(name);
sounds[i] = mySound = new Soundplayer(filename);
```